# Kernel of a map into infinite dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to calculate the kernel of a linear map, but the codomain is infinite dimensional and I'm not sure if there's something that I'm missing.

Let $V$ be a (two-dimensional, with basis $\{1,x\}$) vector space. Consider 
$$d:V \to W$$
where $$W = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{\infty} V^{\otimes 2} = (V \otimes V) \oplus (V \otimes V) \oplus \dots$$

To define the map $d$, let $d_i : V \to V \otimes V$ be given by
$$d_i (1) = 1\otimes x + x \otimes 1$$
$$d_i (x) = x \otimes x$$
for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then define $d = \bigoplus_{i =1}^{\infty} d_i$.

I think the kernel of $d$ will still be $\{0\}$, just as it would be if the direct sum were finite, but I'm not really sure. Weird things happen when you go to infinite dimensions and I'm not sure if I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: Your map $d = \bigoplus_{i =1}^{\infty} d_i$ does not make sense.

Comment: Why do you want to repeat the same thing in infinite many coordinates?

Comment: @Berci: I'm trying to calculate the homology of a chain complex which is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: this doesn't work out.

The direct sum has the property that any collection of maps $V_i \to W$ can be combined to give a map $\oplus V_i \to W$. The direct product has the property that any collection of maps $V \to W_i$ can be combined to give a map $V \to \prod W_i$.

When you have only finitely many things, the direct sum and direct product are the same, so you can use them in either fashion. But when you have infinitely many things, this no longer works.

There is still a relation between them: $\oplus V_i \subseteq \prod V_i$. The direct sum consists of the subspace of elements that have only finitely many nonzero coordinates.

In particular, the map $d$ you want to construct is a map

$$ d : V \to \prod (V \otimes V) $$

and, unfortunately, $d(1)$ has *infinitely* many nonzero coordinates. Therefore, $d$ cannot be construed as a map to $W$.

Comment: If I modified the problem so that $W = \prod (V \otimes V)$, would the map $d: V \to \prod (V \otimes V)$ then make sense? In that case, would we still have $ker(d) = \{0\}$?

Comment: @Mark: Yes: in fact, if you have a collection of maps $f_i : V \to W_i$ and assemble them into a map $f : V \to \prod W_i$, then $$ \ker f = \bigcap_i \ker f_i $$

Comment: Awesome, thanks :D